# exposureMode does not stay locked

Tags: ios4, camera

Problem: I can set the exposureMode property of AVCaptureDevice, but it does not stay locked.

Here is my code:

```
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];
NSError *error;
for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
    if (([device hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) && 
        ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) ) {
        if ([device isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeLocked]) {
            device.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureModeLocked;
            NSLog(@"Exposure locked");
        }
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
}
```

I take 4 pictures one after another programmatically.  The exposure stays locked in the first two pictures, but becomes unlocked in the last two.  This happens when before locking the exposure I tap on a dark portion of the camera view so that part of the picture is over-exposed.  It looks like iOS decides to do auto-exposure and override the exposure lock mode when the picture is overexposed.

thanks for the help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem seem to have been fixed in iOS 5.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this, but going down this same path. Why not try holding the lock until you are done the series of photos. Once you release the lock the system is free to change the setting.